# GSuite Alert Center "list" action error 401

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-alert-center-api

I'm trying to use the REST API for retrieving the GSuite Alert Center alerts - [doc](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/reference/rest/v1beta1/alerts/list)

I've been doing the calls via the Java SDK (artifact `google-api-services-alertcenter`, version `v1beta1-rev20190725-1.30.1`).

I have a GCP Service Account, to which I gave the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.alerts` OAuth scope, yet the API returns error `401 Unauthorized`.

Are there any additional scopes that I'm missing?
How can I find which?

Answer (score 0):

You can go here on the G Suite administration panel to authorize wit your client id and scopes : https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients